# How to MouseEvent.Click on Multiple Movie Clips in Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, mouseevent

I have an array of Movie Clips that are added to the stage by a timer event. This Movie Clip is called `mSquare`.Now I wanted to set up a `EventListener` for the Movie clip so whenever the user clicks on the Movie Clip then it is destroyed, But I am having trouble setting this up since there is an Array of them Added to the stage.
I keep getting this Error:

> Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Here is what I got so far:

```
mSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mIsDown);
```

Now in the `mIsDown` Function I know I have to go through the array so i tried to set up something like this:

```
private function mIsDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{       
    for (var i:int = 0; i < aSquareArray.length; i++)
    {
        //Get current Square in i loop
        var currentSquare:mcSquare = aSquareArray[i];

        if (    )
        {
             trace(currentSquare + "Mouse Is Down");
        }
   }
}
```

Also here is how my Square is added to the stage:

```
private function addSquare(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
     mSquare = new mcSquare();
     stage.addChildAt(mSquare, 0);
     mSquare.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
     mSquare.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) + 450;

     aSquareArray.push(mSquare);
     // trace(aSquareArray.length);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated on what i need to do in order for the user to be able to MOUSE.click or MouseDown for the array of movie clips thanks!

************************** Here is how I am doing it now***************************

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, movieClipHandler); 

private function movieClipHandler(e:MouseEvent):void //test
    {
        mouseIsDown = true; 
        mSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, squareIsBeingClicked);
    }

private function squareIsBeingClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {

         var square:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject; // HERE is your clicked square
         var i:int = aSquareArray.indexOf(square); // and HERE is your index in the array

         if (i < 0) 
         {
            // the MC is out of the array
               trace("Clicked");
               checkSquareIsClicked();


         } else 
         {
            // the MC is in the array

         }


   }


  private function checkSquareIsClicked():void 
    {


        for (var i:int = 0; i < aSquareArray.length; i++)
        {

            var currentSquare:mcSquare = aSquareArray[i];

            if (mouseIsDown)
            {
                aSquareArray.splice(i, 1);
                currentSquare.destroySquare();
                nLives --;
                mouseIsDown = false;

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use the `target` property of the event passed into the listener. This way you don't need to traverse the array in order to find what MC was clicked, you get it as target and go. To get the position of the targetted MC in the array, call `indexOf` function.

```
private function mIsDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var mc:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject; // HERE is your clicked square
    var i:int=aSquareArray.indexOf(mc); // and HERE is your index in the array
    if (i<0) {
        // the MC is out of the array
    } else {
        // the MC is in the array
    }
}
```

Comment: okay that makes sense. I was trying to do something with the current target last Night, but didnt think of the index. Kinda new to that. So would I have to change my mouse EventListener to stage.addevent? or keep it as mSquare.addeventListener because whenever I test the movie i get the error on that specific line:  Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: Well I added the mSquare = new mcSquare(); in my Constructor Function and the error went away. Still just cant seem to get a trace on the mIsDown Function. ah!

Comment: Just Mainly confused on the if statement? How would i use that to check if the square object is being clicked on??

Comment: You add this listener to every object you want to react as written in the listener's code. That is, you add `mSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mIsDown)` whenever you make another `mSquare`. But, don't forget to do `mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mIsDown)` in case you are removing the said `mc` from display.

Comment: Oh I see so i dont need to do anything like mSquare[i].addeventListener? Saw that around some forums. So me adding the mSquare = new mcSquare(); in my constructor function then again in my addSquare timer event function is perfectly fine? Just been at this for awhile now and I understand most of what you wrote and helped me with but confused on what to add in the if(i<0) statement? Thanks Vesp you've been helping me for awhile now sorry if im asking too much.

Comment: Yes, while you have a local variable referencing an object, you are free to use that to add listeners, etc. You don't need to add another listener to the same object after you've pushed it into your array.

Comment: Alright then ill give it a try right now and let you know how it goes thanks!

Comment: Hey Vesper So it seems to be working. But the only problem I am having is that its not fully registering the mouse_down event on all the Squares. It works sometimes but when it does work I have to either keep clicking or click at a certain spot I updated the code above maybe you can help me out if i did it right. Thanks

Comment: Or if anyone can check if that is the correct way of handling the mouse events with those movie clips?

Comment: Yeah this doesnt seem to be registering accurately at all. Whenever i try to click on the square it removes a square that i never clicked on

Comment: If so, whenever you click at a square, do `trace(mc.name)`, and record these. It's possible that you are processing first clicks wrongly, if so, you should get duplicate name in your traced list of names. The names are listed like `instance123` where "123" is an ever increasing number.